# haml, blocks and partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, haml, ruby-on-rails-3.2

To clean and factor ugly views, I'd like to do the following:

1) In the view:

```
= document_left_container do
 = document_information
```

2) In my helper:

```
  def document_left_container(&block)
    render partial: "/document_left_container", locals: { custom_block: block }
  end

   def document_information
    render partial: "document_information"
  end
```

3) Partials:

For document_left_container:

```
.foo
  = custom_block.call
```

For document_information:

```
.bar
```

4) The expected result:

```
<div class='foo'>
  <div class='bar'>
  </div> 
</div>
```

5) The actual result:

```
<div class='foo'>
</div>
<div class='bar'>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how I could do to get my stuff working?

Thanks in advance,

Ben

Comment: Does changing `= document_information` to `- document_information` (i.e. use `-` instead of `=`) help? I can’t reproduce exactly what you’re seeing, but making that change generates your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd keep it DRY:

```
=content_for(:document_information) do
  .bar

.foo
  =yield(:document_information)
```

This will produce

```
<div class='foo'>
  <div class='bar'>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up using `content_for` as described above to keep the global structure. Yet I don't understand why my original code failed...

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is:

Helper:

```
def document_left_container(&block)
  content_for :document_left_container do
    block.call
  end
  render partial: "/document_left_container"
end
```

Partial:

```
.foo
  = yield :document_left_container
```

Rest remains unchanged, I really wanted to keep the same structure.

Still curious to understand why my original code failed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your original code failed because you were essentially calling render and then calling render again. So you pushed something onto the *stack* and then pushed something else onto it. If you did this I *think* it would work. (Although I haven't tested it.)

```
def document_left_container(&block)
  capture_haml do 
    render partial: "/document_left_container", locals: { custom_block: block }
  end
end

 def document_information
  render partial: "document_information"
end
```