# How do you render multiple partials in a layout multiple times in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a page with many modules that have variable parts to them such as a header, sub-heading, footer, body, and id. I started by creating a layout and rendering the layout with local variables and a main block to fill the template.

Layout:

```
.container{:id => local_assigns[:id].present? ? id : nil}
    .header
        = title
        = subtitle
    .body
        = yield
    .footer
        = footer
```

View:

```
= render :layout => "shared/example", :locals => {:title => 'Heading', :subtitle => 'Sub heading', :footer => 'closing part'} do
    body of the template
```

That works great, but now I'd like to pass blocks in for the subtitle and footer keeping in mind that there will be multiple instances of this layout in a page. So far the only way I've been able to solve this is by using the [`capture_haml` helper](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#capture_haml-instance_method)

View with Haml as local variable:

```
- exampleSubtitle = capture_haml do
    %h3 subtitle
    %button action
= render :layout => "shared/example", :locals => {:title => 'Heading', :subtitle => exampleSubtitle, :footer => 'closing part'} do
        body of the template
```

This example is a little stripped down to clarify the question. In practice, I worry about the `:locals` hash growing to an "ugly for Haml" size and would like to prevent that if possible.

Is there any way to define contextual content blocks to keep things cleaner?

Wishful thinking view:

```
= render :layout => "shared/example", :locals => {:title => 'Heading'} do
    - content_for :subtitle do
        %h3 subtitle
        %button action
    - content_for :footer do
        %a{href => "#top"} top
    body of the template
```

Wishful layout:

```
.container{:id => local_assigns[:id].present? ? id : nil}
    .header
        = title
        - if content_for?(:subtitle)
            = yield :subtitle
    .body
        = yield
    - if content_for?(:footer)
    .footer
        = yield :footer
```

Comment: couldn't you simply call both the `content_for` statements before calling `render` on your wishful layout?

Comment: @rudolph9 I'll be using the layout multiple times on one page and the content will be different each time. I believe calling the `content_for` out of context will result in all the layouts having the same content instead of specific custom content.

Comment: You would need to define the `content_for` before each time you call render if you would like it to be custom but you also would be passing around extensive strings, parsing them on the fly.

Comment: I answered my own question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461395/haml-blocks-and-partials could be helpful.